# Populate matrix rows by looping over vector where loop interval is larger than 1

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix

I'm trying to populate an matrix via a loop. Given a vector of values and an empty matrix;

```
n <- c(seq(10,100,10))
out <- matrix(ncol=1, nrow=length(n))
```

running this simple loop as an example;

```
for(i in n){
  dostuff <- i*2
  out[i,1] <- dostuff
}
```

gives the error message

`Error in`[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, 1, value = dostuff) : subscript out of bounds`,

as the interval within the vector that the loop is based on is larger than 1 and therefore does not fit the 1:10 index of the matrix rows. Removing `i` from the `out` row index only repeats the result of the last iteration :

```
for(i in n){
  dostuff <- i*2
  out[,1] <- dostuff
  }
```

There is obviously something fundamental about loops that I don't understand. I have looked, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442461/populating-a-data-frame-in-r-in-a-loop) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651474/for-loop-is-not-populating-the-matrix), but have not been able to find a good solution. This is the result I'm looking for:

```
      [,1]
 [1,]   20
 [2,]   40
 [3,]   60
 [4,]   80
 [5,]  100
 [6,]  120
 [7,]  140
 [8,]  160
 [9,]  180
[10,]  200
```

Comment: `1:n`, `for(i in 1:n)` and without loop that would be `out[, 1] <- n*2`

Comment: Why not just `matrix(data = n*2, ncol = 1)`? Should be faster.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns  That is a nice option.  Please make it as an answer

Comment: @JasonAizkalns yes, that is of course much more elegant, but this is just a simplified example. I do a lot of operations in the actual loop (not shown here) and need to write the results into a matrix. However, due to the mismatch between the vector interval (10) and the row index interval (1), I have had problems doing so.